# Contact information in android

Tags: android, email, contacts

i want to get the email associated with the contact like i have a number that has a email id also.
how to get that email address
i am using code

```
Cursor cur = cr2.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        try {
            Cobj = new JSONObject();
            Cobj.put(
                    "name",
                    cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));

            Cobj.put(
                    "number",
                    cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));

            arContactsobj.put(aC, Cobj);
            aC++;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email`?

Comment: it gives emails but not the email associated with contacts